# Iterable Derived class from file class in Python 2.6

Tags: python, file, generator, enumerate

I've a workaround, but I'm still thinking of a better way of achieve my goal. I want a class derived from base class **file** to access a file line by line, but getting the line number by the way. Something like a *built-in* **enumerate** feature.

I think the class should be like this:

```
class file2(file):
  def __init__(self, filename):
    file.__init__(self, filename)
    self._num_line = 0

  def __iter__(self):
    self._num_line = 0
    ?
```

to achieve this

```
f2 = file2('myfile.txt')
for num_line, line in f2:
  ...
```

My current option is to create a generator inside the child class:

```
    def lines(self):
        for line in self:
            self._num_line += 1
            yield (self._num_line, line)
```

but usage is ugly (well, not as pythonic as I would like it to be):

```
f2 = file2('myfile.txt')
gen = f2.lines()
for i, lin in gen:
   ...
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Python *2.6*?? Are you sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `__iter__` method could just have the exact same implementation as `def lines(self):`

Alternatively you could do:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return enumerate(file.__iter__(self))
```

Or perhaps

```
def __iter__(self):
    return enumerate(super(file, self).__iter__())
```

Note, I shouldn't encourage this because it breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle. Your iter method now returns an iterator of tuples, not an iterator of strings. Just use `enumerate` on the object itself. Why use inheritance at all?